# Big Sur: switch on Do Not Disturb whenever I have a calendar event

Tags: calendar, big-sur, do-not-disturb

I've not found anything when searching, but can't imagine other's haven't had the same request.

I use OSX's (Big Sur) in-built calendar app and have a Google calendar in there which has all my meetings (I also use this to block out 'quiet time' so I can get my head down). What I'd like to do is to automatically switch on Do Not Disturb (to prevent all notifications) whilst I'm in a meeting, and then for it to be switched off again when the meeting ends.

There doesn't seem to be any way to do it in the notification preferences (I already switch off when mirroring), and I can't find a way to do it in Automator either.

Has anyone managed to find a way to do this? Many thanks!